# Sonarqube upgrade from 5.6.3 to 6.7.2 but Dashboards are missing

Tags: sonarqube

we upgraded Sonarqube to 6.7.2 version and this new version does not have the Dashboards and also configure widgets option with in the project custom dashboard is not available, is there a way to achieve the missing dashborads and custom widgets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a reason [the Upgrade docs](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Upgrading) advise you to read the release notes for each intervening version. Dashboards were dropped in SonarQube 6.2.

You'll find that in 6.7.* you have the ability to visualize your measure values in each project's Measures page, and to see measure history graphs on the project Activity page. There are also some cross-project visualizations in the Projects page. If you nonetheless still need additional features, then you have the option to write a plugin to [add a page to the interface](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/DEV/Creating+a+Page).